# Advantage in using SerialPort.ReadByte over ReadChar?

Tags: c#, serial-port, c#-5.0

Of all the example codes I have read online regarding SerialPorts all uses ReadByte then convert to Character instead of using ReadChar in the first place.

Is there a advantage in doing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `SerialPort` to know for sure, but I'd suspect that `ReadChar` may not read a single byte depending on the character encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SerialPort.Encoding property is often misunderstood.  The default is ASCIIEncoding, it will produce ? for byte values 0x80..0xFF.  So they don't like getting these question marks.  If you see such code then converting the byte to char directly then they are getting it really wrong, Unicode has lots of [unprintable codepoints](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) in that byte range and the odds that the device actually meant to send these characters are zero.  A string tends to be regarded as easier to handle than a byte[], it is.

Answer (score 3):

When you use ReadChar it is based on the encoding you are using, like @Preston Guillot said. According to the docu of [ReadChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readchar.aspx):

> This method reads one complete character based on the encoding.
>
> Use caution when using [ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte.aspx) and ReadChar together. Switching
>   between reading bytes and reading characters can cause extra data to
>   be read and/or other unintended behavior. If it is necessary to switch
>   between reading text and reading binary data from the stream, select a
>   protocol that carefully defines the boundary between text and binary
>   data, such as manually reading bytes and decoding the data.